# Extract a dynamic substring from string

Tags: php, html, string, codeigniter

---

i am working on a project, in this project i have a requirement of tag friends in comment like [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com) did. 
i done almost all things for tagging a friend but "notify to user" -> this task will blow my mind because when i am retrieving comment with tagged user it look like this:

```
<a class="red" contenteditable="false" href="http://localhost:8080/review/index.php/user/wall/136">Rashid&nbsp;Hussain</a>
```

i have 2 questions,

> 1) how can i differentiate that comment have tagged user or not.
>
> 2) how can i retrieve user id from href in comment looks like this "136" after "user/wall/"

========================================================================

note: i dont know id length that id has 1 int, 2 int, 3 int or maybe 4 int

I've tried this

```
strpos($comment, $findme);
```

but the point is i dont know the lenth of int.

answer me please as fast as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) Finding ID from url:

```
preg_match('/user\/wall\/(\d+)/', $url, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate it, I am new to it.

Comment: What? Just replace `$url` with You own string or variable.

Comment: thank you bro you made my day i was looking for last 3 day about that issue thanks again. but still my 1st question stucked

Answer (score 1):

if you have your link like

```
<a class="red" contenteditable="false" href="http://localhost:8080/review/index.php/user/wall/136">Rashid&nbsp;Hussain</a>
```

you have in your localhost/htdocs/review folder, inside do you have your project in CI
Then user is your controller, wall your method and 136 your param (user_id)

try

```
class User extends CI_Controller{
    function wall( $user_id ){
        echo $user_id;
    }
}
```